# SQL Bitwise not (~)

Tags: sql, bit-manipulation

Can someone please explain why

```
select ~1
```

gives the result

```
-2
```

Perhaps there is a lot for me to learn about the actual bits of number types.  What resource would you recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read about Two's Complement ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement))

+1 in binary is represented as `00000001`, the inverse of which is `11111110`, which is -2 in Two's Complement

Answer (score 6):

Q: Can someone please explain why select ~1 gives the result -2?

A: For the same reason ~0 would give -1 :)

Here's a good article on "twos complement" arithmetic:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos_complement

Most CPU architectures are two's complement (vs. one's complement).  From the same article:

> Two's complement is the easiest to implement in hardware, which may be
>   the ultimate reason for its widespread popularity[citation needed].
>   Processors on the early mainframes often consisted of thousands of
>   transistors – eliminating a significant number of transistors was a
>   significant cost savings. The architects of the early integrated
>   circuit-based CPUs (Intel 8080, etc.) chose to use two's complement
>   math. As IC technology advanced, virtually all adopted two's
>   complement technology. Intel, AMD, and Power Architecture chips are
>   all two's complement.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do binary (yes/no) bitwise not; then first cast the data as a BIT and then apply bitwise not.

```
SELECT ~CAST( 1 AS BIT)
```

gives the result

```
0
```

Since BIT only has three values: 0, 1 and NULL it will always inverse from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0.
~NULL will always end up as NULL.

Comment: I tried doing sum( ~ ISNULL(date) )  and got a ludicrously large number. Aparently ISNULL returns an integer type, which sounds terribly unnecessary as it's only two return values are 1 and 0. Your casting would help, but sounds unnecessarily cumbersome.

Comment: ~ is a bitwise NOT, not a boolean NOT. It is surprising that MS has separated the two, when they should be the same. Anyways a bitwise NOT (i.e. ~ ) is not supposed to return only 0 and 1. It returns the same data type it is being operated on, but with every bit in the value flipped, as required. It is surprising (and probably useless) that it works on DATE fields, but that's MS for you.